# Multiple touch fabric js

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, touch-event

I have a question, i've added (with custom build) the "gesture" part. 
There is "EventJS" in this build so.

The problem is, when i'm on the tablet, 2 persons can't rotate an object in the canvas.
In fact, the multiple touch isn't working. 
How to get like with EventJS 12 fingers working with fabric JS and give the possibility to get 2 users rotating img on my canvas at the same time ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is that object selectable? Can you select the object by touching it? Also what tablet and what version of fabric-js you are using?

Comment: I've got the lastest version of FabricJS, and yes the object is selectable,